# Does a spell with a target of "You" work if cast by a Swarm on itself?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, swarm

Herbert is a Rat Swarm with Psychic levels.

As such, he is able to cast magic and has the Int score on the level of a wizard.

HOWEVER.

> A swarm is immune to any spell or effect that targets a specific
>   number of creatures (including single-target spells such as
>   disintegrate), with the exception of mind-affecting effects (charms,
>   compulsions, morale effects, patterns, and phantasms) if the swarm has
>   an Intelligence score and a hive mind.

This tells me that while Herbert is immune to spells like Disintegrate or Magic Missile, it is also Immune to Haste or Cure Wounds spells.

Now, the Question!

I do notice that I have spells with a target of "You".

Is there any ruling that would tell me whether such a spell "targets a specific number of creatures" and therefore would function on a Swarm? Not looking for interpretations or guesses, just hard rules!

(This question only applies to non-mental spells, as a Swarm with a hive mind has no immunity to mind-affecting spells.)

Comment: It seems like a lot of trouble to [*awaken*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/awaken) a [rat swam](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/rat/rat-swarm) one rat at a time so the rat swarm can take levels in a casting class. Is this an actual problem or a thought exercise?

Comment: Herbert already has the class levels as a Psychic. I'm asking about Personal spells, and whether it can cast them on itself. It's a character in a game, I'm trying to build Herbert's spell list.

Comment: What method was used to get Herbert the wizard-like Int score and the Psychic levels in the first place? By strict RAW, a rat swarm isn't eligible to take levels in PC classes, nor is it able to get a high Int just by "rolling well" for its ability scores, so something else must be going on here to enable those things, and what that "something else" is is very likely to be relevant to the answer to this question.

Comment: The character isn't rules-legal, we just added mental stats to a swarm, I'm just asking whether there is any ruling about Personal range spells and Swarms.

Comment: If the character isn't possible to create based on the rules then we cannot construct any answers that are based on the rules, and can only offer pure opinions (which are off topic). The practical answer then is “continue making things up that make sense to you”. :)

Comment: Isn't there a similar creature that is a mass of undead insects inside a corpse or something?  It might have some guidance if someone can recall its name.

Comment: @gatherer818 You might be thinking of a Worm that Walks. Another creature that might be relevant here is the Cranium Rat, which I think was introduced in 2e as part of the Planescape Campaign Setting.

Comment: I'm still not seeing how "Is there a rule that says whether This counts as That" is opinion-based. I don't see how "can you create an Intelligent Rat Swarm" has anything to do with it. Help on clarifying my question?